# Discard reading the files when read one file fails during SFTP streaming

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I am reading files one by one from remote directory using SFTP. To perform this I am using LS gateway, followed by split, GET gateway and then in the end rename the file.

Sequence of files is very important for me, so the name of the file is having the count. I want that if after streaming the file using GET gateway there if some issue occurs with data or while data processing, I don`t want that the next files in the sequence gets read.

```
IntegrationFlows.from(() -> path, e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
.handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), LS, "payload")
        .regexFileNameFilter(".*csv"))
.split()
.handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), GET, "payload.remoteDirectory + payload.filename").options(STREAM).temporaryFileSuffix("_reading"))
.handle(readCsvData(), e -> e.advice(afterReadingCsv()))
.filter(this, "checkSuccess")
.enrichHeaders(h -> h
        .headerExpression(FileHeaders.RENAME_TO, "headers[file_remoteDirectory] + 'archive/' + headers[file_remoteFile]")
        .headerExpression(FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE, "headers[file_remoteFile]")
        .header(FileHeaders.REMOTE_DIRECTORY, "headers[file_remoteDirectory]"))
.handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), MV, "headers[file_remoteDirectory]+headers[file_remoteFile]").renameExpression("headers['file_renameTo']"))
.get();
```

I even don`t want to rename the file if there is some issue while data processing, I am able to stop that flow but I am not sure how I can stop the flow to read the subsequent files.

Comment: That is what will happen by default, if the processing of a single file throws an exception, the remaining files from the LS gateway won't be processed.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking: when all the flow is sequential in the same thread, in case of an exception on some step, the rest won't be handled, because of an exception. The behavior is exactly the same if you throw an exception from the regular java loop.

Comment: I got the issue, I was returning an error to integration flow instead I had to throw an error which will stop the flow.